# Adding sites to a DCA in R

Tags: r, vegan

I created a Detrended correspondence analysis (DCA) displaying the species using the script below but I'm wanting to add the sites to it. I know I can do this with the simple script of: `plot(vare.dca)`, but not sure how I do this once I have improved the graphics. I'm new to R so apologises if this is a very simple question. Many thanks for any help!

```
bugs<-read.csv(file= "bugs.csv", row.names='Sites', sep=",", header=TRUE)
env<-read.csv(file= "envir.csv", row.names='Sites', sep=",", header=TRUE) 
library(vegan)

shnam <- make.cepnames(names(bugs)) # abbreviate Latin names
identify(pl, "sp", labels=shnam)
plot(vare.dca, dis="sp", type="n")
sel <- orditorp (vare.dca, dis="species", lab=shnam, pcol = "grey", pch="+")
```

The data for 'bugs' and 'env' are here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dcf0fad859eb879014b2

Comment: Since you are new to R, it would be useful to read: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example If you can `dput(head(bugs))` and `dput(head(env))` that would help those who have no idea what DCA is.

Comment: Debt Collection Agency?

Comment: Your code is incomplete; you show a redundant `identify()` call, but crucially not the call to `decorana()` to fit the DCA, a function that most people here will not be aware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general way is to use the `points()` methods, as in

```
points(vare.dca, display = "sites", col = "red")
```

or use the `text()` method if you want the site/sample labels.

`orditorp()` can also be used, just change the argument to `display = "sites"`, which you could have ascertained by reading `?orditorp`.

There are a number of other options, most notably `ordipointlabel()` which will work harder to stop overlap of various labels.

I've written a number of blog posts on these functions in **vegan**, which you can consult for more explanation and examples

1. [Decluttering ordination plots in vegan part 1: ordilabel()](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2013/01/12/decluttering-ordination-plots-in-vegan-part-1-ordilabel/)
2. [Decluttering ordination plots in vegan part 2: orditorp()](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2013/01/13/decluttering-ordination-plots-in-vegan-part-2-orditorp/)
3. [Decluttering ordination plots part 3: ordipointlabel()](http://www.fromthebottomoftheheap.net/2013/06/27/decluttering-ordination-plots-in-vegan-part-3-ordipointlabel/)